# untabify and remove trailing whitespaces in emacs

Tags: emacs, whitespace

I'm working on large scale project where in there are ~100 engineers working on many files. I would like to see if I could add customization in emacs to remove trailing white spaces and untabify the lines which i'm editing. It wont be good idea to untabify and remove whitespaces in large files which are not related my changes. (I agree, everyone in the team should be following some basic rules. What to do, sometime it doesn't work in that way. :( ).

Currently I've enabled:

```
(show-ws-toggle-show-trailing-whitespace)
(show-ws-toggle-show-tabs)
```

Issue with these options, it makes all over files either yellow or white if owner of the file hasn't fixed his tabs and trailing whitespaces.

It would be great if you could point me to emacs options which will enable me "remove whitespaces and tabs on lines which I'm editing" (not all over the files).

Comment: Could you clarify?  It sounds like you just want to map a function over all open buffers, rather than a bunch of files, is that right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've used the [ws-trim.el](ftp://ftp.lysator.liu.se/pub/emacs/ws-trim.el) package ever since I started using Emacs.  It works like a charm; configure it and forget it.

```
;;;; ************************************************************************
;;;; *** strip trailing whitespace on write
;;;; ************************************************************************
;;;; ------------------------------------------------------------------------
;;;; --- ws-trim.el - [1.3] ftp://ftp.lysator.liu.se/pub/emacs/ws-trim.el
;;;; ------------------------------------------------------------------------
(require 'ws-trim)
(global-ws-trim-mode t)
(set-default 'ws-trim-level 2)
(setq ws-trim-global-modes '(guess (not message-mode eshell-mode)))
(add-hook 'ws-trim-method-hook 'joc-no-tabs-in-java-hook)

(defun joc-no-tabs-in-java-hook ()
  "WS-TRIM Hook to strip all tabs in Java mode only"
  (interactive)
  (if (string= major-mode "jde-mode")
      (ws-trim-tabs)))
```

Comment: I tried ws-trim and unfortunately it installs a post-command-hook that sometimes generates errors and totally borks org-mode.  For example, when I hit `z' (org-agenda-add-note) from my agenda buffer, the `*Org Note*' buffer doesn't come up.  Then if I try to `C-x b' to switch buffers the minibuffer is only one character wide: each time I type a new character it overwrites the last.

Comment: I may have been unfair to ws-trim; I think this may have been a problem with another package.  I'm trying ws-trim again

Comment: How do you disable it when doing a query-replace?  It modifies the whitespace in multi-line query-replace targets so that they don't match anything.

Answer (score 16):

This is not an answer to your question.  But I suspect you will be interested to know about it:

http://github.com/glasserc/ethan-wspace

It keeps track of whether a file is "clean" (free of trailing whitespace and tabs) when you open it, and will automatically remove them when you save it if and only if it was clean when you started.  This means it will keep a file clean if it started clean, and will leave alone any files that were dirty (i.e. someone else didn't follow the rules).

Comment: I just came across ethan-wspace and it rules

Answer (score 8):

From my crufty old `.emacs` file:

```
(defun clean-whitespace-region (start end)
  "Untabifies, removes trailing whitespace, and re-indents the region"
  (interactive "r")
  (save-excursion
    (untabify start end)
    (c-indent-region start end)
    (replace-regexp "[  ]+$" "" nil start end))) ;// uses literal space and tab chars
```

Invoke `M-x clean-whitespace-region` after selecting or marking a region.

`untabify` replaces tabs with spaces depending on your current `tab-width` settings. I then use `c-indent-region` for when I'm given files with strange `tab-with` values (8, 4, 3, and 2 seem common).

To [remove trailing whitespace in emacs 21+](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DeletingWhitespace#toc3) *in the entire buffer* use `delete-trailing-whitespace` otherwise `regexp-replace` works as above.

Answer (score 2):

I've use this to remove trailing white spaces from the whole document.  I wrote it years ago...

```
;;
;; RM-Trailing-Spaces
;;
(defun rm-trailing-spaces ()
  "Remove spaces at ends of all lines"
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (let ((current (point)))
      (goto-char 0)
      (while (re-search-forward "[ \t]+$" nil t)
        (replace-match "" nil nil))
      (goto-char current))))
```

Comment: and to move new lines should I do `(replace-match "\n" nil nil))` right?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete trailing whitespaces on the current line, use the following command :

```
(defun delete-trailing-whitespace-of-current-line ()
  "Delete all the trailing whitespace on the current line.
All whitespace after the last non-whitespace character in a line is deleted.
This respects narrowing, created by \\[narrow-to-region] and friends."
  (interactive "*")
  (save-match-data
    (save-excursion
      (move-to-column 0)
      (if (re-search-forward "\\s-$" nil t)
        (progn
          (skip-syntax-backward "-" (save-excursion (forward-line 0) (point)))
          (delete-region (point) (match-end 0)))))))
```

Bind it to whatever key you want.